# How to get wordpress past dated feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

How to get wordpress past dated feed
like 2020 running,
I need to fetch 2018 year posts content via RSS feed from any wordpress site

www.domain.com/feed - current content data showing only
how to fetch old date - post content data